# How to Match a JSON Sub Element with REGEX

Tags: json, regex

If I have the following JSON, How can I regex match the `PI:` Element?

I want to extract `PI : { item:1232, Item2:243... }`

```json
{
Isogen:531,
Nocxium:151,
Zydrine:0,
Megacyte:0,
Morphite:0,
PI:{
Gleaming Alloy:660,
Condensed Alloy:618,
Opulent Compound:772,
Reactive Metals:140,
Crystal Compound:719,
},
Item Name:MK5 Interdiction Spehere,
Skill Module:5/4/0,
Production Cost:600000,
Qty Per BP:3,
Material Efficiency:104
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON in the first place. I think something was lost in the copy-paste. Also you need to be more specific about what you need to do: are you referring to any programming language? Command line? MongoDB? Excel?

Comment: If it really is JSON (which what you have posted is not), why not just use JSON tools instead of regex?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a nested structure, which regular expressions aren't well-suited to parse. If you know that the key you're looking for won't have any objects inside it, then you could match up until the first close brace after the key, with a regex like this:

```
"PI":.*?\}
```

Note that this is not resilient at all if there's weird stuff in your json, but if you're confident that the structure is always going to be simple enough then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not JSON, or it could be JSON stripped of double quotes. As others pointed out, if you original source is JSON it is safer to use a JSON parser (such as `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript). Using regex is possible, but fragile and can break easily.

If you want to use regex try this pattern:

```
PI: *\{[\s\S]*?\}
```

Explanation:

- `PI: *\{` - expect `PI:`, optional spaces, and a `{`
- `[\s\S]*?` - scan non-greedily (`*?`) over any character (`[\s\S]`) until you find:
- `\}` - a `}`

Notes:

- You can use `.*?` instead of `[\s\S]*?` if you use the "dot-all" flag, which is `s` in most regex implementations
- This regex fails if the `PI` construct has nested elements inside
- To parse real JSON try this: `"PI"\s*:\s*\{[\s\S]*?\}`